# What are those 踊り字, their usage, and examples

Tags: usage

I've come across some characters like 々,ヽ,ゝ and so on . I want to know more about them and their usage

Comment: You can start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration_mark

々 is commonly used in contemporary Japanese. I only see ヽ and ゝ with frequency in 明治 Japanese.

Comment: Thanks for coming to JLU. We're happy to try and help you understand Japanese, but I'm afraid that your question is very broad. Too broad to really answer in any meaningful way. If you can specify exactly what it is you want to know, as opposed to just wanting to know "more", then you're likely to get good answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

These are iteration marks. Used to repeat the same kanji / kana in writing.

々 is used in kanji

```
人々 - ひとびと - people
時々 - ときどき - sometimes
```

ゝ is used for repeating hiragana characters and ヽ is used for katakana

Comment: True, but this answer would be a little more useful if it gave some idea about when and how they are used. Should I write キツヽキ to save ink? Can I write 聞ゝたい, 聞々たい or きゝたい or none of them?